# How to trust code in .dir.locals.el and pass the (is it safe) test?

Tags: directory-local-variables

I have this code in my .dir-locals.el file:

```
  (eval . (let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
            (setq-local company-clang-arguments
                        (list (concat "-I" root "headers")
                              (concat "-I" root "source/mon")
                  ))
            (setq-local flycheck-clang-include-path
                        (list (concat root "headers")
                              (concat root "source/mon")
                  ))))
  ))
```

But everytime I start emacs it asks to apply the code and if it is safe (multiple times) and even when choosing the ! option to save my selection it continues to ask these questions on each emacs startup.

How to trust everything in this file and not prompt for this safety warning?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44360145/850781)

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question at the same time on this site and Stack Overflow.  Please pick one or the other.

Comment: You might want to try: https://melpa.org/#/sidecar-locals

Answer (score 1):

Your example code isn't a valid `.dir-locals.el` on its own, but I tested the following `.dir-locals.el`, with the `projectile` package installed from MELPA, and `(require 'projectile)` in my `init.el` (because the `projectile-project-root` function isn't autoloaded), and an empty `TAGS` file in the directory I was testing with, to act as a projectile root, and I did not experience any issues using <kbd>!</kbd> to update the `safe-local-variable-values` in the `custom-set-variables` section of my init file.

```lisp
((nil . ((eval . (let ((root (projectile-project-root)))
                   (setq-local company-clang-arguments
                               (list (concat "-I" root "headers")
                                     (concat "-I" root "source/mon")))
                   (setq-local flycheck-clang-include-path
                               (list (concat root "headers")
                                     (concat root "source/mon"))))))))
```

Assuming there aren't any errors being generated (in which case you should have included them in the question), you should check that you can successfully customize and save *other* values to your init file (or `custom-file`), to ensure it's not just a generic issue with file permissions or something?